# Is there a way to copy lighting to multiple scenes?

Tags: animation, light, workflow, lighting

I'm slowly beginning to understand how to use Blender properly, so now I'm thinking about creating my own animated series. I want to create an efficient workflow in order to achieve this, well, efficiently, and so I have been using the "scenes" feature for test animations. However, in my desired workflow I want to focus completely on the animation first, and when that is done for each scene I could move onto the lighting and adjust that the way I want. However, I have not yet found a way to copy multiple lights (settings, location, etc.) to multiple scenes in a single .blend file. Is there a solution to this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to have objects linked from a scene to another, select your object and go in the header menu > *Object > Make Links > Objects To Scene*, and choose the destination scene:

[image]

Any change on the object on a scene will be replicated on the same object on the other scene. If you ever want the objects to be unlinked, go in the header menu > *Object > Relations > Make Single User > Object & Data & Materials*:

[image]

Comment: Thank you! I'll try it out and see what happens

Comment: Ok I tried it. However, it appears this tactic would seem somewhat burdensome, especially if I wanted to deal with more than a couple scenes. Is there a way I could select multiple scenes to link with at once?

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways to do it.

One of the simplest is to move (press M on the 3D view window) all lights into a new collection, then append or link the collection into the production file. Using append lets you edit the lights in the destination production file, while using link, all edits have to be performed in the source file (useful if you want to use the same light set in many files, and you want to edit all of them in the same way).

Comment: Interesting! I haven't tried out the link feature just yet, but it sounds like it could be useful. Thanks for the response!